# Как считать из xml файла само слово encoding и его значение = "ISO8859-1"

Tags: c#, xml

Как считать из xml файла само слово encoding и его значение = "ISO8859-1"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно загрузить файл и посмотреть на свойство [`XmlDeclaration.Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmldeclaration.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(@"file.xml");
if (xmlDocument.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((XmlDeclaration)xmlDocument.FirstChild).Encoding);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No XML declaration found.");
}
```

Comment: @SVD102 да, так даже проще. Только `Declaration` на null проверяйте. И зачем вам `ElementAt(0)` -- в `Encoding` ведь уже лежит строка?

Comment: string declaration = xDoc.Declaration.Encoding.ToString() - так работает